# Why is the related model not loading into the template even though request returned the correct related model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Basically I have a Badge Template, that has a corresponding Badge Model. Every badge has (belongs to) a mentor. However when I go load the template, the Badge model is called and it's data is displayed. If I check the network requests, the app is requesting the correct mentor, but it is not being displayed on the template. Any idea why this would be happening?

**Badge**

```
App.Badge = DS.Model.extend({
    'category': DS.belongsTo('category'),
    'title': attr('string'),
    'type': attr('string'),
    'ord': attr('number'),
    'short_description': attr('string'),
    'full_description': attr('string'),
  'mentor': DS.belongsTo('employee' , { async: true } ),
  'parent':DS.belongsTo('badge'),
    'icon': attr('string'),
    'required': attr('boolean'),
    'signoff_role': attr('string'),
    'created_at': attr('string'),
    'updated_at': attr('string'),
    'resources': DS.hasMany('resource', { async: true } ),
  'quiz': DS.belongsTo('quiz', { async: true } )
});
```

**Employee**

```
App.Employee = DS.Model.extend({
    'badge': DS.belongsTo('badge', { async:true } ),
    'employee_preferred_name': DS.attr('string'),
    'email': DS.attr('string'),
    'phone': DS.attr('string')
});
```

**Badge Route**

```
App.BadgeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({    

  model: function(params) {
      return this.store.find('badge',params.badge_id); 
  },
    renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('categories',{outlet: "categoriesList"});
    this.render('category',{outlet: "badgeList"});
    this.render('badge',{outlet: "body"});
    this.render('badge/index',{outlet:'badgeBody',into: "badge"})
  }    

});
```

**Badge Template**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-lg-12">
    {{! Section }}
        <h3>Basic Info</h3>
        <hr>
        {{! Tag Line }}
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px">
            <div class="row page-header-title">
                <div class="col col-lg-11">
                    <h4>Tag Line</h4>
                </div>
                {{#view App.EditTagLineView}}
                    <h4 {{bindAttr class=":glyphicon isEditingTagLine:glyphicon-nothing:glyphicon-pencil :edit-button"}}></h4>
                {{/view}}
            </div>
            <div class="container" style="margin-top:1em;">
                {{#if short_description}}
                    {{short_description}}
                {{else}}
                    <span class="text-muted">No Tag Line provided</span>
                {{/if}}
            <div>
        </div>
        {{! Description }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row page-header-title">
                <div class="col col-lg-11">
                    <h4>Description</h4>
                </div>
                {{#view App.EditDescriptionView}}
                    <h4 {{bindAttr class=":glyphicon isEditingTagLine:glyphicon-nothing:glyphicon-pencil :edit-button"}}></h4>
                {{/view}}
            </div>
            <div class="container" style="margin-top:1em;">
                {{#if full_description}}
                    {{markdown full_description}}
                {{else}}
                    <span class="text-muted">No description provided</span>
                {{/if}}
            <div>
        </div>
        {{! Mentor }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row page-header-title">
                <div class="col col-lg-11">
                    <h4>Mentor</h4>
                </div>
                {{#view App.EditDescriptionView}}
                    <h4 {{bindAttr class=":glyphicon isEditingTagLine:glyphicon-nothing:glyphicon-pencil :edit-button"}}></h4>
                {{/view}}
            </div>
            <div class="container" style="margin-top:1em;">
            {{#if mentor}}    

                Name:{{mentor.employee_preferred_name}}<br>
                Email: {{mentor.email}}<br>
                Phone: {{mentor.phone}}
            {{else}}
            wow
            {{/if}}    

            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{!--
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-lg-12">
         <h3>Basic Info</h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="row page-header-title">
            <div class="col col-lg-11">
                <h4>Tag Line</h4>
            </div>

            {{#view App.EditTagLineView}}
                <h4 {{bindAttr class=":glyphicon isEditingTagLine:glyphicon-nothing:glyphicon-pencil :edit-button"}}></h4>
            {{/view}}
        </div>
        <p>
            {{#if isEditingTagLine}}    

                {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="short_description" class="form-control" style="padding-top:10px"}}
                <hr>
                <button {{action saveTagLine}} class="btn btn-success">Save</button>    

            {{else}}    

                {{#if short_description}}    

                    {{short_description}}    

                {{else}}    

                    No tag line provided    

                {{/if}}    

            {{/if}}
        </p>
        <div class="row page-header-title">
        <div class="col col-lg-11">
            <h4>
                Description
            </h4>
        </div>
            {{#view App.EditDescriptionView}}
                <h4 {{bindAttr class=":glyphicon isEditingDescription:glyphicon-nothing:glyphicon-pencil :edit-button"}}></h4>
            {{/view}}
        </div>
        <p>
            {{#if isEditingDescription}}
                {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="full_description" class="form-control" rows="6"}}
                <hr>
                <button {{action saveDescription}} class="btn btn-success">Save</button> 
                <a href="http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax" target="new" class="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> More on Markdown </a>
            {{else}}
                {{#if full_description}}
                    {{markdown full_description}}
                {{else}}
                    <span class="text-muted">no description provided</span>
                {{/if}}
            {{/if}}
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row page-header-title" >
    <div class="col col-lg-11">
        <h4>
            Mentor
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-1">
    <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit-button"></h4>
    </div>
</div>
        {{#if mentor}}
        <address>
            {{log mentor}}
            <strong> {{mentor.employee_preferred_name}}</strong>
            <br>
            {{#if mentor.phone}}
            <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> {{mentor.phone}} <br>
            {{else}}
            <small> no phone number provided </small> <br>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if mentor.email}}
            <abbr title="Email">E:</abbr> {{mentor.email}}
            {{else}}
            <small> no email number provided </small> <br>
            {{/if}}
        </address>    

        {{/if}}
</div>
</div>    

--}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your router and the name of the badge template you defined in the script tag? It would be very helpful.

I would suggest to rename your Badge Route to `App.BadgeIndexRoute` and use a template called `badge/index`.

I've had an issue recently and the reason was that I was not using the correct route and template.